# Getting an multidimentional array from api. Not getting how to use it in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, api

Array from API:

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Done","response":[{"id":"34","title":"mix fusion","from":"2017-08-22","to":"2017-08-23","time":"18:30:00","venue":"bardi, nagpur","price":"500","description":"

czcgx<\/p>\r\n","image":"Jellyfish.jpg"},{"id":"17","title":"fusion","from":"2017-08-28","to":"2017-10-01","time":"20:30:00","venue":"police ground, nagpur","price":"500","description":"

sdfgfaaa<\/p>\r\n","image":"Hydrangeas.jpg"},{"id":"49","title":"gdf","from":"2017-09-05","to":"2017-09-05","time":"05:30:00","venue":"fdvf","price":"300","description":"","image":""},{"id":"18","title":"zankkar beats","from":"2017-12-06","to":"2017-12-08","time":"19:55:00","venue":"cine max, bardi, nagpur","price":"700","description":"

asadvad<\/p>\r\n","image":"Tulips6.jpg"}]}
```

---

JS file:

```
var  url_set = 'http://localhost/project/admin/admin/api/';
var  url_set_o = 'http://localhost/project/admin/admin/api/';

app.controller('NewspageCrtl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
        $http.get(url_set+'getDataPage')
       .then(function(response){
                      $scope.records = [
    ]

});
```

---

Also please help me for html page code
Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you can find solutions to your problem but no one will write code for you. Please post relevant code, what you did so far, what is your problems you face. Related to `Also please help me for html page code ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   app.controller('NewspageCrtl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
        $http.get(url_set+'getDataPage')
       .then(function(response){
         $scope.records = response.response;// You will get your response array here

     console.log($scope.records)// check console data

    //If you want read it You can use array

  for(var i=0;i<$scope.records.length;i++){
      console.log($scope.records[i].title)
     }

});
```

Comment: Even your JSON is not proper.Once you get the response validate json first   .Here is the link to validate-  https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: `response.response` is not what is wanted

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still not working

Comment: Thanks , It worked.

Comment: Welcome.Please upvote.